# Detecting Python interpreters and installing a site-package from WiX Installer

Tags: python, deployment, pip, wix, windows-installer

I am currently extending an existing installer based on WiX to deliver a Python API (let's call it `PythonAPI`) that was newly implemented for some software. I have added the necessary files to the installer and they are being placed in the appropriate position (say `C:\Program Files\SomeSoftware\PythonAPI`). I am able to install the API via pip with the command

```
python -m pip install "C:\Program Files\SomeSoftware\PythonAPI"
```

This allows me to select the python version for which I want to install the package by selecting the appropriate python interpreter. This package for example is only compatible with python3.6 and above.

My question is: How do I find installed python interpreters with the help of WiX and use the appropriate one to run the installation command above?

The simplest way would be to assume there is an appropriate python interpreter in the `PATH`, but I don't want to rely on that. Instead I assume it would be best to check the registry for keys like

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\versionnumber\InstallPath`
- `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\versionnumber\InstallPath`

where `versionnumber` is something like `3.6` to get the install path and use this absolute path to the interpreter. However if I understand the [RegistrySearch](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrysearch.html) feature of WiX correctly, it would be hard to scan for multiple versions (`>=3.6`) since I have to give the full key path (in this case including `versionnumber`). I could of course hard code checks for the currently available versions (`3.6`, `3.7` and `3.8`) but this would mean I have to manually extend this every time a new python release comes along.

Once the correct interpreter is selected I would assume a [CustomAction](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html) could be used to run the install command mentioned above.